# Unable to properly start Sorbet VSCode Extension

Tags: ruby, vscode-extensions, sorbet

I need to run Sorbet VSCode extension in order to enable the static type check inside the IDE.

Everything has been setted up following the offical doc and I managed to properly run this extension on a different machine before.

The issue is that the extension server seem not to be able to start up: I am getting the following message

```
Sorbet: Restarting
```

On the VSCode console, in the Output tab, the log is the following

```
2023-10-28T21:02:52.513Z [info] Running Sorbet LSP.
[Error - 23:02:52] Connection to server is erroring. Shutting down server.
[Error - 23:02:52] Connection to server is erroring. Shutting down server.
```

The machine setup is:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- VSCode 1.83.1
- rbenv 1.2
- Ruby 3.1.4

In addition a bit of info about the actual code config

Gemfile

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gemspec

group :development do
  gem 'bundler'
  gem 'fasterer'
  gem 'minitest'
  gem 'rake'
  gem 'rubocop', require: false
  gem 'sorbet'
  gem 'tapioca', require: false
  gem 'webmock'
end
```

.gemspec

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require_relative 'lib/****/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = ****
  spec.version       = ****
  spec.authors       = ****
  spec.email         = ****

  spec.summary       = ****
  spec.description   = ****
  spec.homepage      = ****
  spec.required_ruby_version = '>= 3.1'

  spec.metadata['homepage_uri'] = ****

  spec.files = Dir.chdir(File.expand_path(__dir__)) do
    `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject { |f| f.match(%r{\A(?:test|spec|features)/}) }
  end
  spec.bindir        = 'exe'
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{\Aexe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.require_paths = ['lib']

end
```

I already tried to clean up: vscode, rbenv and all the gems installed on the machine by deleting and installing all of them again but nothing really changed.

Comment: Does it work on the command line, e.g with `bundle exec srb tc`?

Comment: I can run the sorbet stand alone using this command. But I need to enable the Extension Too.

Comment: Can you also try `bundle exec srb tc --lsp` to see if it reports any error.

Comment: It simply stucks and show nothing until I stop the execution.

Comment: That's to be expected since it's waiting for a request. But it's useful to know there's no error reported.